# Can a German declaration of division (Teliungserklärung) or community ordinance (Gemeinschaftsordnung) prohibit long-term rentals?

Tags: rental-property, germany, homeownership

Consider an apartment block consisting of three equal units A, B, and C, located in Bavaria, Germany.  At present, all are owner-occupied and the Community of Apartment Owners (*Wohnungseigentümergemeinschaft*) has three members Asani, Bahar, and Camille, with equal power.  Units B and C are on the market and are bought by Diya, who decides to rent them out.  Now Asani finds himself having a minority in the Community of Apartment Owners and, as an owner-occupier, having other needs and interests than Diya, but Diya can possibly push through or block any decisions taken by majority vote (depending on the specifics in the declaration of division (*Teilungserklärung*), a person owning two units may have either one or two votes).  This situation is not desirable for Asani.

Is it legally possible in Bavaria, Germany, to enact a rule that restricts the rights of owners to rent out their property long-term?  For example, could it contain

- a rule that every owner must live in their property, or
- that the majority of homes must be owner-occupied, or
- that new rentals are not allowed, or
- that everyone who owns a property in the building must also live in the building, or
- something similar?

Such a rule would need to be changeable only by unanimous consent, otherwise Diya owning two out of three properties could simply abolish the rule, so Asani, Bahar, and Camille would together agree on such a rule (perhaps Asani would pay Bahar and Camille in case they fear the rule might reduce the sale value, but that is separate from the legal question).

I've searched the web about restrictions on renting out, but all I find is either about restrictions on *short-term* (holiday) rentals, or about owner-occupiers objecting to *specific* prospective tenants.  I couldn't find anything about the possibility to restrict long-term rentals *in general*.  Is there any law that would prevent the rules governing the property as a whole (such as the Declaration of Division (*Teilungserklärung*) or the Community Ordinance (*Gemeinschaftsordnung*)) from containing such a restriction?

I am primarily interested in the situation in Bavaria, Germany, but for context it's also interesting to know the situation elsewhere.

Comment: I would strongly doubt that you can put any rule in the Teilungserklärung that can only be changed by unanimous consent. That seems to go against the spirit of what the laws regulating this are trying to achieve.

Comment: @quarague My understanding was that changing the *Teilungserklärung* always requires unanimous consent, unlike other rules that can be passed by simple majority.  I read there are also cases in which a supermajority (75%) suffices, but that is de facto the same if there are only three owners.

Comment: The legal basis for this is: [§8 - Partition by the Owner - Act on the Ownership of Apartments and the Permanent Residential Right (Wohnungseigentumsgesetz, WEG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_woeigg/englisch_woeigg.html#p0050) ; [Teilungserklärung – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teilungserkl%C3%A4rung)

Comment: A **declaration of division** (*Teilungserklärung*) of the owners, that must exist before any division becomes effective, is basicly a form of a **contract** (the basic rules of which then apply). Unless otherwise stated in the original contract (which all parties must aggree to), any changes need the aggreement of all parties. The contract can contain any terms that does not violate other laws. For anything not covered, the default conditions of the [German Civil Code (BGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/index.html) would apply.

Comment: Therefore most of your questions can only be answered by looking at the original *Teilungserklärung*, to see what it contains.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I know changing it requires the consent of all parties; but I expect that, like any contract, provisions contained therein might be null and void if the law states otherwise?

Comment: @gerrit Yes, a **contract** would be pretty low within the *Hierarchy of legal sources* (**Hierarchie der Rechtsquellen** ([Normenhierarchie (Deutschland) – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normenhierarchie_(Deutschland)): *Norm hierarchy* means that within the hierarchy the lower norm is superseded by the higher one).

Comment: @MarkJohnson The English translation apparently corresponds to the rules in 2014, but there have been some [important changes in 2020](https://www.haufe-akademie.de/blog/themen/immobilien-themenbereiche/weg-reform-2020-die-sieben-wichtigsten-aenderungen/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put *pretty much anything* you like into the co-op statutes.
You are actually interested in whether it *makes a difference*, though, whether the sheriff will come enforce a court order if it came to a trial.

> - a rule that every owner must live in their property, or
> - that everyone who owns a property in the building must also live in the building, or

By virtue of indirect effect of basic rights (*mittelbarer Wirkung von Grundrechten*) a court will never issue an order mandating Diya to live in her apartment, Art. 11 GG.
The sheriff will not forcefully “shove” her into her apartment:
“You *must* live here now!”

> - that the majority of homes must be owner-occupied, or

Similar, but Art. 2 I GG.
Vacancy of apartments is legal in Germany.

> - that new rentals are not allowed, or

As soon as Diya is recorded in the *Wohnungsgrundbuch* (apartment register) as the new owner of units B and C, she incontestably assumes the *role* of owner about said units.
If she rents them out despite the co-op statutes forbidding so, she does nothing illegal (that means breaking *state*/*federal* *law*).
After all she *is* indeed the owner, so there is no fraud involved, § 263 Ⅰ StGB.

The fact that she agreed to *not* rent out is a matter between Diya and the co-op.
*No court* will evict the new tenants from units B and C, because Diya has breached *her* obligations.

However, it *might* be a just cause to oust Diya from the co-op, § 17 WEG.
Yet still it requires *severe* grounds as it *essentially* means exercising eminent domain, Art. 14 Ⅲ GG.
I tentatively claim it won’t work out as long as Diya pays her share in maintenance and the tenants chosen by Diya are well-behaved.

> - something similar?

You will need something that produces *evidence*.
“Diya does not live in unit B” is a claim that needs corroboration in court.

> […] restrict long-term rentals *in general*. […]

Tenancy agreements are by default unlimited in time.
Short-term rents are sort of “forbidden” except if *justified* by one of the reasons named in § 575 Ⅰ BGB.
Hence restricting long-term rentals borders on a blanket-ban on *all* rentals.

Comment: Right, I was not careful in my formulation.  By "Can it state x" I meant, of course, it if could state and enforce that.  (See also questions on *Can they sue me*)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem this is not possible.

From the [Gesetz über das Wohnungseigentum und das Dauerwohnrecht (Wohnungseigentumsgesetz - WEG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/woeigg/BJNR001750951.html#BJNR001750951BJNG000102360) (Act on the Ownership of Apartments and the Permanent Residential Right):

> § 13 Rechte des Wohnungseigentümers aus dem Sondereigentum
> (1) Jeder Wohnungseigentümer kann, soweit nicht das Gesetz entgegensteht, mit seinem Sondereigentum nach Belieben verfahren, insbesondere dieses bewohnen, vermieten, verpachten oder in sonstiger Weise nutzen, und andere von Einwirkungen ausschließen.

From the [translation by Iyamide Mahdi in cooperation with the Language Service of the Federal Ministry of Justice](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_woeigg/englisch_woeigg.html#p0050) (based on an older version of the law, but this paragraph appears to not have changed):

> § 13 Rights of the Apartment Owners
> (1) Every apartment owner shall have the right, in the absence of conflicting laws or third party rights, to deal at will with the parts of the building forming part of the separately owned property and in particular to occupy them, rent them out, lease them out or use them in any other manner, and to exclude others from interfering.

I am not a lawyer, but from my reading, it is not possible to restrict by declaration of division or community ordinance the rights of owners to rent out or lease out their property.

Comment: The purpose of § 13 WEG is to legally enshrine the rights § 903 BGB grants. Since § 903 BGB is not applicable to separate ownership, you need to write it out again. It is otherwise _ius dispositivum_, § 10 Ⅰ 2 WEG, as far as it does not offend the fundamental tenets of property law (e. g. the _numerus clausus_ comes to mind).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I'm afraid that, as a legal lay, I don't understand your comment.  Is the conclusion in my answer potentially wrong?

Comment: The issue is, _you_ cannot develop a _new_ legal institute, call it _Wohnungseigentum “light”_, that strips the owner of certain privileges. Only lawmakers can conceive such. You _may_ nevertheless agree among co-op members to _not_ rent out to third parties. It’s _your_ business, the state won’t interfere with that. The state only interferes if you are engaged in criminal activities or if there is some gross imbalance in power among parties (e. g. on the labor market) that requires special protection of one party’s interests.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Right; but the Gemeinschaftsordnung is tied to the property, and thus remains when a property is sold.  An agreement between apartment owners does not bind future owners in any way.  So although Asani, Bahir, and Camille can agree not to rent out their property, they can't promise anything that a future owner does.  Correct?

Comment: Correct, a contract applies _inter partes_, only among the specific parties involved (person X, company Y). By “agreement” I meant they reach consensus about updating the _Gemeinschaftsordnung_ as recorded in the _Wohnungsgrundbuch_. It’s still a contract, _except_ the contracting party is exchangeable by virtue of transferring title. Whoever acquires ownership is bound to this special contract, with all the _regular implications_ a breach of contract brings about. That means you will _still_ need to go to court, the _Grundbuchamt_ won’t enforce nothing on its own accord.